# Event Manager – how to access to event title

Tags: plugins, customization, hooks

I am trying modify the grid- & list-view event title. I need to access the title, test for certain conditions and modify as required. My first thought was to use the template [event_grid_item_format.php] but this uses a placeholder [#_EVENTNAME]. I can get the literal title there using jScript but the issue of modifying the DOM in a loop complicates.

If anyone is familiar with 'Event Manager' and can suggest an access point that would be much appreciated. Thank you.